# How can I exclude a result from a graph?

Tags: jmeter

I need to exclude a result from a graph in Jmeter because my graph is getting a few issues with two of them.

How can I exclude those results? I´m using the filters but I can only use one.

Thanks guys

Comment: Which graph are you using?

Comment: I´m using the default aggregate graph! But already solved this problem. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter [.jtl files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) are basically CSV files, open it with with your favourite text/CSV editor and simply remove the "unwanted" values
2. You can [change granularity](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general), if you increase it - most probably it will "hide" the outstanding values
3. If you can distinguish the values you want to remove by tracing it down to particular [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) labels you can filter them out using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) or [Filter Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/), both provide `--exclude-labels` command-line argument where you can specify which samplers you don't want to see in results/charts.

Comment: Thanks man! I will open it with excell, remove the unwanted values and then open it with Jmeter graph tool.